# Date falls between two dates and matches one date from table in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to check if an application date falls between a range of policy applicationBeginDate and policy applicationEndDate I have a table that stores these dates and the Effective date that needs to match as well. My method needs to return a boolean value of true or false and I am lost.

The error I am receiving is that > operator cannot be applied to operands of type DateTime and Iqueryable.

```
var applicationBeginDates = _app2Lead.DataAccess.App2BonusPromos.FindAll(x => x.ApplicationBeginDate);
var effectiveDates = _app2Lead.DataAccess.App2BonusPromos.FindAll(x => x.EffectiveDate);    
var applicationEndDate = _app2Lead.DataAccess.App2BonusPromos.FindAll(x => x.ApplicationEndDate);

if (policyApplicationDate > applicationBeginDates && policyApplicationDate < applicationEndDate && policyEffectiveDate == effectiveDates)
{
    return true;
}

return false;
```

[image: Datesintable]

[image]

Comment: So what is the error message you're getting? We only have half the problem at the moment. (And please post the code as *text*, not a screenshot.)

Comment: @JonSkeet first off, whoa talking to a legend! cool!. Second thank you for looking at my question.

Comment: something like `return _app2Lead.DataAccess.App2BonusPromos.Any(x => x.ApplicationBeginDate < policyApplicationDate && x.ApplicationEndDate > policyApplicationDate && x.EffectiveDate == policyEffectiveDate)` maybe?

Comment: Okay... so what's the type of `applicationBeginDates`? It looks like it's a *collection* of objects. What does it mean for a collection to be later than a date? It sounds like really you should be tweaking your `FindAll` query to perform the test in the database itself.

Comment: stephen.vakil that worked perfectly! thank you so much. @JonSkeet that makes all the sense in the world. It is awesome that you are imparting knowledge here on stackoverflow. Thanks again for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @stephen.vakil and the suggestion from @JonSkeet i was able to use this to get what i needed. Thank you for your help!.

```
  var duh = _app2Lead.DataAccess.App2BonusPromos.FindByExp(
                x =>
                    x.ApplicationBeginDate < policyApplicationDate && x.ApplicationEndDate > policyApplicationDate &&
                    x.EffectiveDate == policyEffectiveDate).Any();

            if (duh)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
```